# How to get all dropdown values

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc

i've a case where i have to get the total of all the dropdown elements. i'm able to achieve it individually. and the below is the code that worked for individual selection.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
    <title>JSP Page</title>  
</head>  
<body><form name="Reports" method="post" action="Reports.jsp"><table><tr><td>  
    Select user:<select name="user" id="user">  
        <option value="">Select User</option>  
        <option value="Rakesh">Rakesh</option>  
        <option value="Hari">Hari</option>  
    </select></td><td>  
    Select Type:<select name="type" id="type">  
        <option value="'Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll'">All</option>  
        <option value="Updates">Updates</option>    
        <option value="Multibases">Multibases</option>  
        <option value="DAIS">DAIS</option>  
        <option value="Acds">Admin Codes</option>  
        <option value="Legis">Legis</option>  
        <option value="LegAll">Legis-All</option>  
            </select></td>  
            <td><input type="submit" value="Generate" id="sub1" name="sub1"></td></tr>  
    </table> </form>   </body>
```

and the jsp is below

```
<%--   
Document   : Reports  
Created on : Oct 25, 2012, 4:53:23 PM  
Author     : u0138039  
--%>  

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  

</head>  
<body><table>  
    <%  

    String[] a=request.getParameterValues("type");  
    String b=request.getParameter("user");  
    try{  
        ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from Scope1");  

        ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type ='"+a+"' and Specialist='"+b+"'");  
        rs=ps.executeQuery();  
        while(rs.next())  
                           {%>  
                           <tr>  
                               <td><%=a%>:</td><td>  
                               <%=rs.getString(1)%>  
                               </td></tr>  
      <% }  

                   }  
    catch(Exception e)  
    {  
        out.println(e);  
}  
%>
```

and to retrieve all the values from drop down i use the below sql code

```
SELECT SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type IN ('All','Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and Specialist='b';
```

and to retrieve individually i use the below code

```
 ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type IN ('"+a+"') and Specialist='"+b+"'");
```

i want this to be in a single statement and also i want the output to be displayed in a table format when i select all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see is in this statement

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 
where type ='"+a+"' and Specialist='"+b+"'");
```

because `a` is of array type and when you assign that in the above sql statement you mentioned as `a` without array index. Hence this sql statement must be failing.

```
String[] a=request.getParameterValues("type");
```

Edit

I could see another problem which is

```
<%=rs.getString(1)%>
```

you should use

```
<%=rs.getInt(1)%>
```

because `SELECT SUM(Update_Count)` return number, so `getString` will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to adjust the query to pull back the type column, and include a group by. 
This will then give you multiple rows in the result set. 
You will need to programmatically adjust what is inside the IN clause as appropriate.

SELECT SUM(Update_Count), type FROM Scope1 where type IN ('All','Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and Specialist='b' 
group by type;

Comment: thanks for the reply dude, but when i'm trying to do a group by it is just giving a blank page as output.

Comment: @Rakesh are you sure you are able to retrieve values from database?

Comment: when i'm using the query separately i'm able to, it is also working in sql.

Comment: @Rakesh Try to debug code starting from database connection and print sql statements in jsp.

Comment: here i took off the array and just made it to be String a = request.getParameter("type");